# How can I detect a rectangular region of interest in a picture?

Tags: image-processing, image

Here is a downsampled input image I converted to greyscale.

[image]

To select the rectangular region of interest we first preform preprocessing:

```
binarizedImage = 
 Dilation[Erosion[
   Dilation[Binarize[FillingTransform@ColorNegate@resizedGreyImage], 
    3], 4], 3]
```

And then find the relevant components and corners

```
regions = 
 SelectComponents[
  DeleteSmallComponents[binarizedImage, 
   Method -> "Mean"], {"Rectangularity"}, 1]

corners = 
 ImageCorners[regions, 4, 0, 10, MaxFeatures -> 4, 
  "MaxRefinement" -> 0]
```

Here is the result:

```
Show[input, 
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], PointSize[.05], Yellow, 
   Polygon[corners[[ConvexHull[corners]]]], Thickness[0.4], Blue, 
   Point /@ corners, White, Text[ToString@#, #] & /@ corners, Green, 
   Point /@ centers, EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], FaceForm[Opacity[0]], 
   Rectangle @@ # & /@ boundingBoxes}], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

I'd like this to be more robust. I'm not sure that "Rectangularity" is the best measure, for instance, in this picture, selecting the component with highest "Rectangularity" doesn't always work:

```
![enter code here][3]

DeleteSmallComponents[
     ImageForestingComponents[ImageResize[input, 300]]]

% // Colorize
regions = SelectComponents[%%, {"Rectangularity"}, 1] // Colorize
```

[image]

Also, I'm coding this in opencv, I'm only using mathematica to prototype so if you know the underlying methods used that would be very helpful.

Here are some test images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I wonder how do you distinguish your "rectangular" ROI from other "rectangular" items in your picture

Comment: Probably center screen, greater area, better edge contrast.

Comment: What's making it hard to answer this question is that we don't have a good idea of the scope of the kinds of rectangles that you really want to identify. If it really is just this one, then you can do so by clicking on four points! Do you have a collection of images where we can see the target rectangle(s).

Comment: Yes, I'll add them.

Comment: Also, I don't think downsampling and color conversion as a first step is a good idea. You may be losing useful info.

Comment: Maybe not, speed is important and we can save a copy of the original to compare against.

Comment: You should look at nikie's answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13918/5) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5676/5) for some ideas...

Comment: I've seen that, but her method fails in the second step on all on my images, the heuristic of taking the largest filled binary region is waaaaay too simplistic to work somewhat generally.

Comment: (a) you're not planning to code this in *Mathematica* eventually, and (b) "Rectangularity" seems poorly defined. Kind of hard to find a good starting point.

Comment: Finding four straight (-ish) lines with angles that add to approximately 360 degrees might be fruitful....

Comment: @geordie But how to tell apart a rectangle with parallax from a planar parallelogram? Or how to distinguish a rectangle in a 3D scene with perspective vanishing points from a trapezoid in 2D? And how rounded are the corners allowed to be? I think this problem isn't a good fit for this forum.

Comment: @Jens Fair point. I was assuming that the goal was to find 'potential' rectangles not just actual rectangles. I realise this is a somewhat idiosyncratic distinction... "Ceci n'est pas une pipe"

Comment: @M.R. Do you know what `SelectComponents`' equivalent function is in opencv? Do you have a reference suggestion?

Comment: I wonder if `SelectComponents` convex hull properties, `Opening` with a `BoxMatrix` or `DiamondMatrix`, and perhaps the number of convex hull points could be of use

Answer (score 13):

It's more a region-of-interest detection than a rectangle identification algorithm and still half-baked, but anyway: (using Mma 8.0 on WinXP)

```
l = {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/t95sV.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVP47.jpg", 
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpiLb.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHHZ4.jpg", 
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlFpH.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7YO9.jpg", 
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCHSm.jpg"};

i = ImageResize[#, 500] & /@ (Import /@ l);
i1 = ColorSeparate[#, "HSB"][[2]] & /@ i;
ie1 = EdgeDetect /@ ImageAdjust /@ (LaplacianGaussianFilter[#, 2] & /@ i1);
dc1 = DeleteSmallComponents[#, 100] & /@ ie1;
lines1 = ImageLines[#, .15, .611] & /@ dc1;
slope[{p1_, p2_}] := (p2[[2]] - p1[[2]])/(p2[[1]] - p1[[1]])
Show[#[[1]], Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line /@ #[[2]]}], 
      ImageSize -> 100] & /@ Transpose[{i, lines1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The next step is to discard those lines whose slopes are not paired/grouped  within a tolerance. I need only some spare time ...

Comment: I just tried your code (V9, Win7) and I only get 1 red line per image...

Comment: Same here with v8 on Win7.

Comment: @SimonWoods I'm using Mma 8.0 on WinXP

Comment: @s0rce Probably the Imagelines[] function isn't consistent across platforms.

Comment: @belisarius You're still using 8.0.0, right? Probably the same issue as in your answer on DSP.

Comment: @rm-rf Well, I'm unable to test and fix it on another platform, so ...

Comment: @rm-rf A couple of bug fixes in version 9 must explain the difference in performance. Altering a bit the parameters set by belisarius should produce proper results.

Comment: @MatthiasOdisio Do you care to edit the answer with the modified parms for v9?

Comment: @belisarius Setting LaplacianGaussianFilter to 6 and parameters for ImageLines to .111 and .207 yield roughly comparable results on my 9.0.1 on OSX. Don't ask me what has changed, maybe some parameters inside Hough transform ImageLines uses?

Answer (score 13):

At his request, this is how I would edit @belisarius's answers (using 9.0.1):

```
l = {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/t95sV.jpg", 
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVP47.jpg",
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpiLb.jpg",
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHHZ4.jpg",
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlFpH.jpg",
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7YO9.jpg",
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCHSm.jpg"};

i = ImageResize[Import@#, 500] & /@ l;
i1 = Flatten[ColorSeparate[#, "Saturation"] & /@ i];
ie1 = EdgeDetect[#, 6, .04] & /@ i1;
dc1 = DeleteSmallComponents[#, 100] & /@ ie1;
lines1 = ImageLines[#, 0, .2, MaxFeatures -> 4] & /@ dc1;

Show[#[[1]], Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line /@ #[[2]]}], ImageSize -> 100] & /@ Transpose[{i, lines1}]
```

[image]

It still looks a bit fragile though. With grayscale images, the saturation channel is black. In these cases (`ImageMeasurements[saturation, "Max"] == 0.`), one just goes ahead using the actual image, not the saturation map.

Comment: Yeah, it's very fragile. I get very different results using 9.0.0 on OS X. It works on only two of the images :/

Comment: I meant fragile with respect to the input images, not to software bugs (Upgrade to 9.0.1 if possible).  I have not tried this method on other images, and I'm pretty sure it's not the silver bullet, but it provides a good result under some circumstances.